# tower.js server.js Bundle error on startup

Tags: javascript-framework, towerjs, startup-error

i am trying to get tower.js up and running. it looks awesome but i'm hitting a snag that seems to have something to do with the package itself.

if i run `$tower new myapp` or `$tower create app myapp` i get the following error:
`node_modules/tower-server/index.js:46
       this.bundle = new Bundle(this);
     ReferenceError: Bundle is not defined`

when i look at index.js i see a line at the top commented out that defines Bundle:

```
/**
  * Module dependendencies.
 */

var application = {};
var express = require('express');
var sockjs = require('sockjs');
//var Bundle = require('tower-bundle');
var http = require('http');
var instance;`
```

tower-bundle is not in npm repos. i tried commenting out the Bundle instantiation but then nothing happens. i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. any help is greatly appreciated.

i should also mention i installed tower and tower-cli globally using npm and i am running node 0.10+ (latest version as of this date.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the maintainers of Tower here. The best way to get help is through Github issues. That's where we're active.

Yes, that command is currently not working. The bundler is also not complete, thus why it was commented out. Right now, we were concentrating mostly on the client-side of things. Right now, there's no use for scaffolding, but we'll be getting the server-side up to standards.

If you need any help, please visit our Github repositories, we'll be glad to help. FYI, the IRC channel is useless right now, we're never on it.

Comment: Thanks. Filed a bug report on github.